# Is Date saved the string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, lumen

I have a problem, which I researched a lot, I tried several ways, but I did not find the solution, I need to save the current date in a document in mongodb I am using Lumen, but when I put the date it saves as a string, in this case I was using date(y-m-d ), I tried to pass the dateTime() but it returns an object, if anyone knows a way to save it as a date I would be very grateful.

```
$xml = new XML; 
$xml->data_upload = date('y-m-d'); 
$xml->save();
```

Comment: What driver are you using?